# Jazz.net forum redesign legal or not?

Tags: discussion, copyright

I have discovered that Jazz.net had redesigned their [forum](https://jazz.net/forum/) recently and now it looks awfully similar to the Stack Exchange family sites.
Is this legal or not? Or maybe they just licensed the design, I just can't find any reference there to SE.
PS: their old forum was completely different - like vBulletin or similar. Just plain forum.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be legal? There are many clones http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones

Comment: Stack Exchange may have perfected the concept of Questions and Answers, but it doesn't own the idea.

Comment: Are they copying any content?

Comment: Layout is almost the same. Links and their order are the same. Badges, rewards, marking correct answers, etc. Almost everything is the same. I didn't know that there are so many clones. I guess its pointless in this situation to research one site. A pity that IBM steps so low :( . At least they could credit SE for "idea" :) .

Comment: Even though this turned out to be legal, +1 for a good eye and taking the time to post on Meta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're using [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/), which is one of the [various clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) out there.

They're not copying our CSS or data (and even the latter could be fine given [proper attribution](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/)), so there's nothing illegal about this.

Comment: I'm just waiting for the day some major blogger criticizes Stack Overflow's "derivative design"

Comment: Worth noting that "they" is actually IBM - Always good when the big boys get inspired by you...